# Strange Chrome rendering text in textbox issue

Tags: html, google-chrome

[image]

As you can see in this image I have a text box, when the user click on the textbox and starts typing the placeholder disappears and you begin typing. Although what ever you type on the first line, the text renders in a strange way.

[image]

If you look closely at the screen shot you can see white lines around the g and also along the line, these disappear once you drop down a line so is it something to do with the placeholder?

See it in action here
http://joshhornby.co.uk/typewriter/